# binn serialization - correct syntax for reading a binn object from a socket

Tags: c, sockets, serialization, deserialization

I am trying to read a binn object from a socket and can't get the data,
for the example it's an int.

binn is a binary serialization format.
details can be found here: 
https://github.com/liteserver/binn

sending:

```
binn * obj = binn_object();

binn_object_set_int32(obj, (char*)"dst_enclave", 12345678);

int socket = clSockFd;

if (send(socket, binn_ptr(obj), binn_size(obj), 0) != binn_size(obj)) {
    printf("SENDER -- failed to send msg1 to dest\n");
    abort();
}
binn_free(obj);
```

and trying to recieve:

```
binn * obj = binn_object();

if (recv(servSockFd, binn_ptr(obj), binn_size(obj), 0) < 0) {
    printf("LISTENER -- failed to read msg1 from src\n");
    abort();
}

int test = binn_object_int32(obj, (char*)"dst_enclave");
```

after reading from the socket i get 0 value in test.

I have read the documentation for binn, but they don't exactly specify how to recv..
searched the web as well.

btw the problem is not with the sockets, i'm getting other messages fine before that.

Comment: What is a "binn object"? What library are you using?

Comment: binn:
https://github.com/liteserver/binn
binary serialization.

Comment: Edit the information into the question.

Comment: when calling `send()`, check the returned value for <0 to check for errors, then check for =0 to check for receiver closed, then, check for all bytes sent and when not all bytes sent, loop to send the rest of the bytes.

Comment: when calling `recv(), check the returned value for <0 to check for errors, then check for =0 to check for transmitter closed, then, loop to receive bytes, until all bytes received.

Comment: ERROR messages should be sent to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  When responding to an error indication from a system function, also display the text string for the value of `errno`.  A very good method for doing this is: `perror( "recv failed" );` as that will output to `stderr` the enclosed text plus the system text related to the error.